# Wordpress submenu

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

I want to create a horizontal submenu in wordpress with wp_nav_menu();

As it is now I output the whole menu with wp_nav_menu but since the children is outputted inside theire parents I cant make a submenu. Just a dropdown menu.

I want it to look some what like this. *Home*, *articles*, *about* and *contact* are pages and *inspiration*, *technology* and *interview* are categories.

Home **Articles** About Contact
Inspiration Technology Interview
*(if I have pressed on Articles)*

So this is what it looks like:

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Articles
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Inspiration</li>
      <li>Technology</li>
      <li>Interview</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

And this is what I want:

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Articles</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
<ul class="submenu">
  <li>Inspiration</li>
  <li>Technology</li>
  <li>Interview</li>
</ul>
```

Someone got and idea? :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify template code, you should do this with css.

Sample here : http://jsfiddle.net/2G9dQ/1/

Comment: the template code is my own. But ok, so how to do it with css then?

Comment: Apparently you don't know jsfiddle : click on the link and you will see

Comment: @soju: I only see the "zegzeg" as well.

Comment: Ah, nice! Never though of using position:absolute.

Comment: Well, i guess this solves the problem. After multiple weeks of searching on google. The solution is just simple css. HAHA Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just create 2 separated menus, in wp-admin.

Comment: Mm but then you'll lose the hiarchi :/

Comment: And i need some way to connect the pages and categories?

Comment: Why connect pages and categories? Aren't you using your custom CSS?
You lose the hierarchy when you separate <ul>'s.. Maybe @soju solution is better for you.

Comment: I lose the hierarchy in php. To get the right categories for the right mainmenu.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [wp_list_pages()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) instead of [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) so you can have the main and sub menus with something like this:

```
<ul id="mainmenu">
    <?php wp_list_pages("title_li=&depth=1"); ?>
</ul>
<ul id="submenu">
    <?php wp_list_pages("title_li=&depth=1&child_of=".$post->post_parent ); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: wp_list_pages will not display a menu built in the menu panel

Comment: Yeah, but i want the categories in the menu as well. If I use wp_list_pages i can only list pages.

Comment: @soju: true. @Patrik: also true. I can't think of a way to do it with wp_nav_menu I am afraid.

Comment: Don't be afraid :) it is just a css issue

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to post a second answer, but it is a completely different solution with jQuery (just one line of js though): http://jsfiddle.net/AFC2r/. The CSS there is obviously just to make it appear clearer.

```
$(function() {
    $(".mainmenu .submenu").detach().insertAfter('.mainmenu');
});
```

Depending on your needs, soju's CSS-only solution could be better of course.

Comment: Ah, nice. That can be useful :)